# Updating 2 tables and creating history from a asp web page

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have a web page for enquiry details in that page end user updates their status regarding the enquiry.

[image: web page]

here is the page that the user can update their status [image: status update]

and my `sql` query is

```
update enquiries_dtls
  set dctname = '"& name_upd &"',
      region = '"& city_upd &"',
      enquiry = '"& enquiry_upd &"',
      stsupdate = '"& stus_upd &"',
      dtupdate = '"& dt_upd &"',
      closingdate = '"& clsngdt_upd &"',
      clsedby = '"& clsdby_upd &"',
      revenue = '"& estrev_upd &"',
      apprstatus = '"& apprsts_upd &"',
      [clsed] = '"& clsd_upd &"'
 where sno = '"& Request("sno_edt") &"'
```

but If I use update statement it overwrites the previous status update.
[image: needed]

I need to get the history of the particular enquiry..

I would appreciate your input and help.

Comment: Why are you updating? You have to insert if you want new row to get created.

Comment: ya i just used this insert query too.. INSERT INTO [enquiries] ([stsupdate], [dtupdate], enqId) 
   SELECT stsupdate, dtupdate , enqId
   FROM enquiries_dtls eqd
   WHERE enqId = eqd.enqId and eqd.enqId = 'enq2'..if i insert i have to have the data right..

Comment: A user calls up his enquiry - the form is prepopulated with his data.  He makes changes where necessary and the contents of the entire form are inserted as a new row, so you have multiple rows detailing the history of the enquiry.  When the user checks on the status you can make sure they see data from the most recent row with a query along the lines of "SELECT top 1 * from Enquiries where enquiryid = "& rs("enquiryid") &" order by datelastupdated desc"